# Combine multiple text files (row wise) into columns

Tags: bash, text

I have multiple text files that I want to merge columnwise.

For example:

File 1

```
0.698501 -0.0747351 0.122993 -2.13516
```

File 2

```
-5.27203 -3.5916 -0.871368 1.53945
```

I want the output file to be like:

```
0.698501, -5.27203
-0.0747351, -3.5916
0.122993, -0.871368
-2.13516, 1.53945
```

Is there a one line bash common that can accomplish this?

I'll appreciate any help.
---Lyndz

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: manually using excel.

Comment: `cat file1 file2 | datamash -W transpose` if you have datamash, if not, I'm pretty sure this has been asked and answered several times here but I don't have time to find a nice duplicate

Comment: This might help: `paste -d "," <(xargs -n 1 <file1) <(xargs -n 1 <file2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '{if(NR==1) {split($0,a1," ")} else {split($0,a2," ")}} END{for(i in a2) print a1[i] ", " a2[i]}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
0.698501, -5.27203
-0.0747351, -3.5916
0.122993, -0.871368
-2.13516, 1.53945
```

Answer (score 1):

```
paste <(cat file1 | sed -E 's/ +/&,\n/g') <(cat file2 | sed -E 's/ +/&\n/g') | column -s $',' -t | sed -E 's/\s+/, /g' | sed -E 's/, $//g'
```

It got a bit complicated, but I guess it can be done in a bit simpler way also.

P.S: Please lookup for the man pages of each command to see what they do.

Comment: In this way you have best performance:


`paste <(sed -E 's/ +/&,\n/g' file1) <(sed -E 's/ +/&\n/g' file2) | column -s $',' -t | sed -E 's/\s+/, /g;s/, $//g'`


Check those: [avoid cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) and [avoid pipes](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/put-down-pipe)

Comment: Thanks for those posts @FrancescoLucianò.